# List comprehensions with arguments drawn from the same list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've a question regarding list comprehensions in Haskell.

I have an exam later this week and therefore did some old exams where I found this question:

"Write a function that given a positive integer n returns a list of positive integers m ≤ n such that there are two positive integers x and y, such that x^2 + y^3 = m. The list needs to be sorted"

There were two possible answers, 
either

```
squareCube::Int->[Int]
squareCube n =[a|a<-[1..n],x<-[1..n],y<-[1..n],x^2+y^3==a]
```

or

```
import Data.List
squareCube::Int->[Int]
squareCube n =
sort [a|x<-[1..n],y<-[1..n],a<-[1..n],x^2+y^3==a]
```

I wonder why I need to use the sort function when a comes after x and y in my comprehension. Why does the order between the arguments matter?

Comment: Considering lists _as sets_, it's doesn't make any difference whether you sort the end result. If the order is important, it better be specified in the question.

Comment: According to the task, it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that in my question. The list needs to be sorted. @leftaroundabout

Comment: So your question is really: _why is `[a|a<-[1..n],x<-[1..n],y<-[1..n],x^2+y^3==a]` sorted?_

Comment: Yes. And why it isn't sorted when a comes after x and y.

Comment: Omit the sort, omit the filter, [observe what happens](https://ideone.com/jHxxAO), explain.

Comment: By the way `..., a<-[1..n], x^2+y^3==a]` is an antipattern, which will slow down your code considerably. This tries all values in `[1..n]` just to see if `x^2+y^3` is there. It would be much better to `let a = x^2+y^3` and require `1 <= a , a <= n`. In this way we move from O(n) to O(1) complexity.

Comment: I did that but I didn't really get why it happened the way it did, that's why I asked a question. Thank you! @chi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a sort function when `a` comes after `x` and `y` in the comprehension because of the order of evaluation. If `a <- [1..]` is called first, each of the subsequent statements will be evaluated against each `a` in turn, so the `a`'s already form an increasing list:

```
a = 1
  x <- [1..n]
    y <- [1..n]
    ...return a if there's a valid match

a = 2
    x <- [1..n]
      y <- [1..n]
      ...return a if there's a valid match

etc.
```

However, if `a <- [1..n]` is evaluated last, we may not get an ordered sequence of `a`s:

```
  x = 1
    y <- [1..n]
      ...
      y = 1
        a <- [1..n]
        ...
        a = 2                 2
      y = 2
        a <- [1..n]
        ...
        a = 9                 9

  x = 2
    y <- [1..n]
      ...
      y = 1
        a <- [1..n]
        ...
        a = 5                 5
```

Answer (score 4):

This list is sorted:

```
    [ 1, 1, 1
    , 2, 2, 2
    , 3, 3, 3
    , 4, 4, 4 ]
```

This one isn't:

```
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4
    , 1, 2, 3, 4
    , 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: Okay. So when a comes after x and y we will draw every argument for x and then go to y and do the same etc?

Answer (score 1):

This is only vaguely related to the question: it addresses the programming challenge, but does not answer the question as asked about why the existing approaches work. But it was too fun to avoid writing a snippet about it, so here goes.

With appropriate imports, you can very efficiently generate even the infinite list of square-cube sums. The basic idea is to make an infinite list of infinite lists; we will maintain the invariant that the outer infinite list is sorted by the heads of the inner infinite lists. Then it's easy and efficient to merge all of these. With [the appropriate package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) it's a one-liner, and very succinctly matches the problem description:

```
import Data.List.Ordered
squareCubes = unionAll [[x^2+y^3 | x <- [1..]] | y <- [1..]]
```

We can compare the efficiency of this to the existing two approaches. Here's the test program, which I compiled with `-O2`:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Ordered
import System.Environment

squareCubes = unionAll [[x^2+y^3 | x <- [1..]] | y <- [1..]]
squareCube n = takeWhile (<=n) squareCubes
squareCube' n = [a|a<-[1..n],x<-[1..n],y<-[1..n],x^2+y^3==a]
squareCube'' n = sort [a|x<-[1..n],y<-[1..n],a<-[1..n],x^2+y^3==a]

main = do
    [kind, limit] <- getArgs
    let f = case kind of
            "inf" -> squareCube
            "unsorted" -> squareCube'
            "sorted" -> squareCube''
    print . sum . f . read $ limit
```

And here are the timings, which are quite stark indeed:

```
% /usr/bin/time ./test unsorted 700  
57465
9.60user 0.01system 0:09.63elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4156maxresident)k
% /usr/bin/time ./test sorted 700 
57465
1.87user 0.00system 0:01.87elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4056maxresident)k
% /usr/bin/time ./test inf 700   
50895
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3616maxresident)k
```

The others take seconds (aeons in computer time) while the one that's in some ways more capable than the others doesn't even register on the timer! I also experimented to find how large of an input we could give before arriving at the timings for the other two implementations. I found that an input of 500000000 takes 8.88 seconds -- almost six orders of magnitude higher in the roughly the same time.

Wait, wait, you say: those outputs are different. So what gives? Well, it turns out that the slow implementations have what I consider to be a bug: they will spit out a single number multiple times if there are multiple ways to construct it as the sum of squares and cubes. For example,

```
> squareCube' 17
[2,5,9,10,12,17,17]
> squareCube 17
[2,5,9,10,12,17]
```

because 3^2 + 2^3 = 4^2 + 1^3. On the other hand, if this is the intended behavior, one can easily achieve it in the efficient, lazy one-liner by replacing `unionAll` with `mergeAll`.

Answer (score 0):

To see clearly what's going on with list comprehensions, try

```
do { print [  (x,[10..13])           | x <- [1,2]]
   ; print [ [(x,y) | y <- [10..13]] | x <- [1,2]]
   ; print [ r                       | x <- [1,2], r <- [(x,y) | y <- [10..13]]]
   ; print [  (x,y)                  | x <- [1,2],               y <- [10..13] ] 
   }
=>
[ (1,[10,11,12,13]),             (2,[10,11,12,13])           ]
[[(1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(1,13)], [(2,10),(2,11),(2,12),(2,13)]]
[ (1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(1,13),   (2,10),(2,11),(2,12),(2,13) ]
[ (1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(1,13),   (2,10),(2,11),(2,12),(2,13) ]
```

On the other hand,

```
do { print [  ([1,2],y)              | y <- [10..13] ]
   ; print [  (x,y)                  | y <- [10..13], x <- [1,2] ]
   }
=>
[ ([1,2],10),    ([1,2],11),    ([1,2],12),    ([1,2],13)    ]
[ (1,10),(2,10), (1,11),(2,11), (1,12),(2,12), (1,13),(2,13) ]
```

List comprehensions work in the *nested* fashion.

---

You could re-write your first code as

```
map (\(a,_,_) -> a) $
  filter (\(a,x,y) -> x^2+y^3==a) $
    liftA3 (,,) [1..n] [1..n] [1..n]     -- (1)
```

and the second as

```
map (\(_,_,a) -> a) $
  filter (\(x,y,a) -> x^2+y^3==a) $
    liftA3 (,,) [1..n] [1..n] [1..n]     -- (2)
```

You could be tempted to see `(1)` and `(2)` as a very general "all combinations of three elements drawn from same list" thing. But Haskell is a *deterministic* language. It produces the same results for the same inputs. Thus it imposes a certain order on the resulting list.

And this is what it means when we say that list comprehensions work in a nested fashion — the leftmost list's element changes the slowest, and the rightmost's the fastest, in the resulting combination — like in an odometer.

---

To solve your problem, you could write

```
sort [a | x2 <- takeWhile (<= n) [x^2    | x <- [1..]]
        , a  <- takeWhile (<= n) [x2+y^3 | y <- [1..]] ]
```

but this requires careful thought, the code doesn't express the original intent as clearly, and isn't still as optimal as the one using `Data.List.Ordered.mergeAll` (from `data-ordlist` package) as seen in the answer by Daniel Wagner,

```
takeWhile (<= n) . mergeAll $ [[x^2+y^3 | x <- [1..]] | y <- [1..]]
```

although both have the same time complexity, more or less. `mergeAll` merges the ordered non-decreasing lists it is presented with, by using pairwise merges arranged in a tree [slanted to the right](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Tree_merging).

Come to think of it, we too could write the more natural-looking

```
   sort . concat . map (takeWhile (<= n))   
                 $ [[x^2+y^3 | x <- [1..n]] | y <- [1..n]]
```

This doesn't work with the infinite list of lists. To fix this, we could write

```
-- sort . concat . takeWhile (not . null) . map (takeWhile (<= n)) 
   sort . concat . map (takeWhile (<= n)) . takeWhile ((<= n).head)
                 $ [[x^2+y^3 | x <- [1..]] | y <- [1..]]
```

In Haskell, it is quite often better not to try too hard to figure it all out ourselves, but leave it to the lazy evaluation to take care of things. Here it didn't quite worked unfortunately, and we had to take special care to be able to deal with infinite list<sup>1</sup>, with those explicit `takeWhile`s superfluous to the task's logic.

Indeed it is true, for any *`n`*, that

```
  under n (union a b)         == nub . sort $ under n a ++ under n b
  under n . unionAll . take m == under n . foldl union [] . take m
  under n . unionAll          == nub . sort . concat 
                                     . takeWhile (not.null) . map (under n)
```

and

```
  under n (merge a b)         == sort $ under n a ++ under n b
  under n . mergeAll . take m == under n . foldl merge [] . take m
  under n . mergeAll          == sort . concat 
                                      . takeWhile (not.null) . map (under n)
```

using `under n = takeWhile (<= n)`, with ordered increasing lists.

<sup>1</sup>`Data.List.Ordered.mergeAll` takes care of the infinite lists all by itself, and is better in the sense that it is *on-line* - it starts producing its output much earlier than our tortured constructed function. The point wasn't that the library function isn't needed, but just to see what can be done without it.